# Shifting an image with bilinear interpolation in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, tensor

Suppose that I have an input x of size [H,W] and also a mu_x and mu_y (which may be fractional)representing the pixels in x and y direction to shift. Is there any efficient way in pytorch without using c++ to shift the tensor x for mu_x and mu_y units with bilinear interpolation.

To be more precise, let's say we have an image. mu_x = 5 and mu_y = 3, we may want to shift the image so that the image moves rightward 5 pixels and downward 3 pixels, with the pixels out of boundary of [H,W] removed and new pixels introduced at the other end of the boundary to be 0. However, with fractional mu_x and mu_y, we need to use bilinear interpolation to estimate the resulting image.

Is it possible to be implemented with pure pytorch tensor operations? Or do I need to use c++.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not using CUDA"*?

Comment: @Ivan Sorry for the unclarity. I mean without using c++. Basically, is it possible using pure pytorch

Comment: Ideally, this should be possible by manipulating the torch tensor itself. How you manipulate it is you have to replicate what happens in bilinear interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this by applying grid sampling on your original input and using a grid to guide the sampling process. If you take a coordinate grid of your image and sample using that the resulting image will be equal to the original image. However you can apply a shift on this grid and therefore sample with the given shift. Grid sampling works with floating-point grids of course, which means you can apply an arbitrary non-round shift to your image and choose a sampling mode (bilinear is the default).

This can be implemented out of the box with [`F.grid_sampling`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html). Given an image tensor `img`, we first construct a pixel grid of that image using [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.meshgrid.html). Keep in mind the grid used by the sampler must be normalized to `[-1, -1]`. Therefore pixel `x=0,y=0` should be mapped to `(-1,-1)`, pixel `x=w,y=h` mapped to `(1,1)`, and the center pixel will end up at around `(0,0)`.

Use two [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html) with a `[0,1]`-normalization followed by a remapping to `[-1,1]`:

```
>>> c,h,w = img.shape
>>> x, y = torch.arange(h)/(h-1), torch.arange(w)/(w-1)
>>> grid = torch.dstack(torch.meshgrid(x, y))*2-1
```

So the resulting grid has a shape of `(c, h, w)` which will be the dimensions of the output image produced by the sampling process.

Since we are not working with batched elements, we need to unsqueeze singleton dimensions on both `img` and `grid`. Then we can apply `F.grid_sample`:

```
>>> sampled = F.grid_sample(img[None], grid[None])
```

Following this you can apply your arbitrary `mu_x`, `mu_y` shift and even easily use this to batches of images and shifts. The way you would define your sampling is by defining a ***shifted grid***:

```
>>> x_s, y_s = (torch.arange(h)+mu_y)/(h-1), (torch.arange(w)+mu_x)/(w-1)
```

Where mu_x and mu_y are the values in pixels (floating point) with wish which the image is shifted on the horizontal and vertical axes respectively. To acquire the sampled image, apply F.grid_sampling on a grid made up of `x_s` and `y_s`:

```
>>> grid_shifted = torch.dstack(torch.meshgrid(x_s, y_s))*2-1
>>> sampled = F.grid_sample(img[None], grid_shifted[None])
```